# MySQL - order by 3 criteria

Tags: mysql

I need to get MySQL order result like below:

```
id | active |    year | size
----------------------------
1  |      1 | 1Q 2014 | 650
2  |      1 | 3Q 2010 | 200
3  |      1 | 1Q 2010 | 1650
4  |      1 | 4Q 2012 | 0
5  |      0 | 1Q 2014 | 650
6  |      0 | 2Q 2012 | 1200
7  |      0 | 1Q 2014 | 0
```

- most important is active
- next order priority is year from newest to oldest (1Q - 4Q means quarter, so 4Q is newest than 1Q) - provided that the size > 0, 
  if size = 0 - year isn't a priority (record id 4 is below record id 3)

Is this possible in MySQL or in Laravel Eloguent?
Thank you, kind regards,
Paul

Correct answer:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY active DESC,
(size > 0) DESC, 
RIGHT(year, 4) DESC, 
year DESC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit of a pain in MySQL, because the `year` column has an arcane structure.  It would be better to store it as `YYYY Q` format.  Then it would be readily sortable.  But, with some manipulation, you can do what you want:

```
order by active desc,                         -- actives first
         (size > 0) desc,                     -- then size > 0
         substring_index(year, ' ', 2) desc,  -- then order by the year
         year desc;                           -- then order by the quarter
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon :) I needed advice as (size > 0) desc. You really helped me. I added correct answer in my question. Kind regards! :)